# Use Sass to list of duplicate CSS selectors

Tags: sass

Is there a more efficient way to add these prefixes instead of having two lines for each icon? One for `fa-ion-md` and one for `fa-ios-md`

```
$fa-menu-size: 2.4rem;

.menu-inner {

    .#{$fa-ion-md-css-prefix}-glass,
    .#{fa-ion-ios-css-prefix}-glass,
    .#{$fa-ion-md-css-prefix}-music,
    .#{fa-ion-ios-css-prefix}-music,
    [many more icons]
    .#{$fa-ion-md-css-prefix}-meetup,
    .#{fa-ion-ios-css-prefix}-meetup {
        font-size: $fa-menu-size;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way would be to go with the classic [ampersand parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Referencing_Parent_Selectors_____parent-selector) to combine the prefixes with the suffixes:

```
$fa-ion-md-css-prefix: "fa-ion-md";
$fa-ion-ios-css-prefix: "fa-ion-ios";
$fa-menu-size: 2.4rem;

.menu-inner {
    .#{$fa-ion-md-css-prefix},
    .#{$fa-ion-ios-css-prefix} {
      &-glass,
      &-music,
      &-meetup{
        font-size: $fa-menu-size;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use iteration, [DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e5ca4bb59922f6305af002e1a99cabdb)

```
$fa-menu-size: 2.4rem;
$fa-ion-md-css-prefix: "fa-ion-md";
$fa-ion-ios-css-prefix: "fa-ion-ios";

$icons: glass, music, meetup, stuff, things;

@each $icon in $icons {
  #{$fa-ion-md-css-prefix}-#{$icon},
  #{$fa-ion-ios-css-prefix}-#{$icon} {
    font-size: $fa-menu-size;
  }
}
```